# Help distributing and adding noise to curves with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I´m trying to replicate the background elements from this cover and could use some guidance with the set up. So far I´ve tried using both **geometry nodes** and **hair particles**.

[image]

With **geometry nodes** I tried using a mix of *distribute points on faces* and *instance on points* along with some *noise* for the deformation (please see node set up below). This kinda works on a plane, but when applied to a shape I noticed a couple of things:

- The seams between clumps still show even after cranking up the density of the points to around 800, and increasing the radius of the curve circle to hide it somewhat helps but it also creates a lot of overlapping between strands.
- The strands clump at the tips.
- The strands grow evenly from the mesh outward instead of falling back from the seams like on the reference.

Node set up
[image]

Geo nodes on a plane
[image]

Geo nodes on ico sphere
[image]

With **hair particles** it´s been easier to get the subtle randomnes on the folds with a simulation, but I'm getting too much overlapping at the base  and can´t seem to get the blocky shape from the strands so didn't spend too much time on it.

[image]

Any guidance or help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)